# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 within windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, wubi, system-installation

Can you install Ubuntu 14.04 with Wubi within windows 7 so that it can be uninstalled from windows 7 if desired.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the way that the WUBI installer works.  Ubuntu will show up as a program in Control Panel that you can uninstall.

Comment: Consider adding directions on where to obtain Wubi, or a link to a tutorial on how to use wubi in order to make your answer more helpful to a new user.